# ZF2 Form Collection - Using Collection for Doctrine Type "array"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form2

I'm stuck with ZF2! I'm trying to add a Collection element on my form to display an array of phone numbers stored in a simple "array" in my Doctrine entity.

I want to know what is the proper way to get my values working with Doctrine without using a Fieldset as it only need one field (the phone number).

I tried a lot of things but nothing is working. If someone did it, could you tell me please!